# what is facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 c# project which manage the Facebook page posts. I am a newbie in Facebook development. I am exploring about Facebook APIs since last 4 hours and i got the following 2 main APIs for Facebook development in asp.net mvc-5 c#

1. [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/)
2. [Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/10/updating-the-mvc-facebook-api.aspx)

Can anyone - who have previous experience with this Facebook libraries - explain me whats the difference between these 2 libraries and which one is better to use or i have to use both?